# Pass conky object to external script

Tags: bash, parameters, lua, conky

I have a conky object, and I want to pass it as parameter of a `bash` / `lua` script. How do I do it?

## Example:

**conky object**: `${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0}`
i.e the port of the first `tcp` connection

**script**: `$ lsof -i :<PORT> | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $1}'`
i.e finds the process with that port

## What I tried (unsuccessfully):

- `${exec lsof -i :${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0} | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $1}'}`
- `${exec echo $(lsof -i :${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0} | sed -n 2p | awk '{print $1}')}`
- `${lua conky_proc_port ${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0}}`, where `conky_proc_port` simply outputs the parameter

How do I do it?

PS: for reference, [here](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/666) is the link to the Github issue

Answer (score 1):

The best way to pass the conky object to a lua function is... by not passing the object.

Instead, use the lua API function `conky_parse` within the lua function to evaluate the string `'${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0}'` and then process the result as desired.

Alternativly, rather than hardcoding the string, you could pass the string `'${tcp_portmon 1 61000 lport 0}'` to the lua function and then use `conky_parse` on the passed string.

See the "LUA API" section of `man conky` for more info.